# How to sum/total counts by group?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I'm attempting to determine **which practice performed the highest volume annual visits**?

My current code accurately generates the total annual visits for each physician (e.g., npi) but I'm unable to then group the totals by practice. Potentially relevant attributes of the data are (1) some physicians have more than one instance in the first table and (2) some physicians are not in a practice in the second table.

#### Example Table 1: UtilizationPayments

```
   npi             line_srvc_cnt
------------------------------------
1032838184               24
7492740921               106
6294619564               67
1739182018               39
1978476935               81
```

#### Example Table 2: ProviderDimension

```
   npi             organization_legal_name
-------------------------------------------
1032838184         Texas Medical Associates
7492740921         South-West Primary Care
6294619564                  NULL
1739182018         Western Medical Associates
1978476935         Texan Physician Network Inc.
```

I've tried many various iterations of my current code to generate accurate totals by practice.

#### Current Code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    UP.npi AS 'NPI',
    UP.line_srvc_cnt AS 'AnnualVisits_Total',
    ProDim.organization_legal_name AS 'Practice'



FROM CMS_ProviderEP.UtilizationPayments UP

    LEFT JOIN CMS_ProviderEP.ProviderDimension ProDim
        ON UP.npi = ProDim.npi


WHERE UP.hcpcs_code IN ('G0438', 'G0439')
        AND UP.provider_type IN ('Internal Medicine', 'Nurse 
           Practitioner', 'Family Practice', 'General Practice', 
           'Geriatric Medicine', 'Pediatric Medicine')
        AND ProDim.organization_legal_name IS NOT NULL
```

#### What my current code generates

```
   npi      AnnualVisits_Total                  Practice
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1032838184        126                     Texas Medical Associates
7492740921         73                     South-West Primary Care
6294619564         27                     Texan Physician Network Inc.
1739182018        106                     South-West Primary Care
1978476935         84                     Texan Physician Network Inc.
```

#### Desired Outcome

I need the sum of the visits from each physician to be grouped by the practice he or she is associated.

```
    Practice                  AnnualVisits_Total                               
----------------------------------------------------
Texas Medical Associates             126
South-West Primary Care              179
Texan Physician Network Inc.         111
```

Comment: https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-6-how-to-group-and-summarize-your-results/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current code produces the results you posted all you have to do is use it to `group by Practice`

```
SELECT Practice, SUM(AnnualVisits_Total) AS AnnualVisits_Total
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    UP.npi AS 'NPI',
    UP.line_srvc_cnt AS 'AnnualVisits_Total',
    ProDim.organization_legal_name AS 'Practice'
  FROM CMS_ProviderEP.UtilizationPayments UP
  LEFT JOIN CMS_ProviderEP.ProviderDimension ProDim
  ON UP.npi = ProDim.npi
  WHERE UP.hcpcs_code IN ('G0438', 'G0439')
  AND UP.provider_type IN (
    'Internal Medicine', 'Nurse Practitioner', 'Family Practice', 
    'General Practice', 'Geriatric Medicine', 'Pediatric Medicine'
  )
  AND ProDim.organization_legal_name IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY Practice
```